# document.getElementById().value not returning textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to build a delivery optimization app with openstreetmaps, leaflet, javascript with a flask back-end.
The idea is that a delivery manager can click on a map to create a texbox(es) that indicates a delivery point(s) and what she
types in the textbox(es) as the size of the order(s). I am having trouble retrieving the values entered into the textboxes using
document.getElementById().value. I have a leaflet plug-in that I use to search for a location. I also have lists/arrays 
that keep track/process the coordinates of the textboxes and the distribution centre from which orders are filled. 
The list of the textbox coordinates is stringified and assigned to the value of a hidden textbox.

My code for creating the map looks like this:

```
<body onLoad="javascript:init();">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="map">
     <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Submit" />
     <input type="hidden" id="coord1" value="" />
  </div> 
  <script language="javascript">
    var map;
    var str;
    var dc_coords;
    var counter = 0;
    var coordinates = {};
    var customer_orders = {};
    var coords;
    var coords_array;

    function init() {
     map = L.map('map');

     //add a tile layer to add to our map, in this case it's the 'standard' OpenStreetMap.org tile server
     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18

     }).addTo(map);

     map.attributionControl.setPrefix(''); // Don't show the 'Powered by Leaflet' text. Attribution overload


    var nairobi = new L.LatLng(-1.28333,36.81667); // geographical point (longitude and latitude)
    map.setView(nairobi, 13);



    L.marker([-1.28333,36.81667]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('Distribution<br> Centre')
        .openPopup();

    coordinates[counter] = nairobi;
    dc_coords = JSON.stringify(coordinates);


    var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder({placeholder: 'Search location...'});
    // The line above creates the search function for locating places.
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.on('dblclick', onMapClick); // Here I am specifying the handler for the double-click event.
    map.addControl(osmGeocoder);
  }

  .......
  .......
  .......
 </script>
 </body>
```

I am aware that global variables in javascript are a bad practice. Forgive me I am relatively new to javascript. I want to
   solve the problem first. Textboxes are created by double-clicking. The handler code for double-clicking event is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">
   .............
   .............
   .............

   function onMapClick(e) {

   counter++;

   var order_box = '<input type="text" id= ' + '"' + counter + '"' + ' onchange="doSubmit(' + "'" + counter + "'" + ')"' + ' size = "5">';
   // I have also tried oninput and onblur

   var myIcon = new L.divIcon({

      html:order_box
   });
   var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);


    coordinates[counter] = e.latlng;
    str = JSON.stringify(coordinates);

    document.getElementById('coord1').value = str;

  }
  map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
  ................
  ................
  ................
 </script>
```

I have a counter variable that keeps track of the number of textboxes created. Since I can't know how many textboxes 
    will be created before hand, I use the string version of the current value of the counter variable for the id of a 
    textbox just created. I have specified an onchange event on each textbox created that triggers its handler passing 
    the id of the textbox as an argument. The code for the handler is as follows:

```
<script>
    ............
    ............
    ............
    function doSubmit(id_string) {
    alert("id_string: " + id_string);
    alert("type of id_string: " + typeof(id_string));

    coords = document.getElementById('coord1').value;

    coords_array = coords.split("},");

    var customer_order_size = document.getElementById(id_string).value;
    alert("textbox_id: " + document.getElementById(id_string).id);
    alert("customer_order_size: " + customer_order_size);
    var current_element = (coords_array[parseInt(id_string)]).split(":{");

    if(typeof(customer_order_size) != "undefined") {
        var complete_entry = customer_order_size + ":" + current_element[1];

        customer_orders[id_string] = complete_entry;
    }

}
</script>
```

The problem now is that after I enter  a value in the textbox and trigger the doSumbit by removing the focus from the textbox,
    the document.getElementById(id_string).value is returning undefined. I have confirmed that the id is being passed correctly to
    the doSubmit function and that the element exists. I have replaced onchange with onblur and oninput to no avail. I have searched
    high and low, even as far as W3C Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 Events Specification, also to no avail. I would be grateful
    for pointers to what I might be doing wrong. Tested the code with Mozilla Firefox and Chrome, same result. Thanks for the anticipated help.

Comment: Let's back up a bit and focus on the problem with your current approach. Using `id`s is not a great way build build solutions since `id`s must be unique and that forces you to have to know the specific `id` of each element in order to work with it as you are now seeing. Instead, forget `id`s completely - - they are actually rarely needed and avoiding them makes code much easier to scale. Instead, use `class` in your HTML and through DOM APIs in your event handler, you can easily access the correct element(s).

Comment: Also, you should not be using `onXyz` HTML attributes in the first place since they are a 25+ year old way of setting up events. Instead, do your event binding in JavaScript with `addEventListener()`.